# Does anyone know how to apply a premade eyebrow in blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, import, color

Hi this may sound stupid. I'm a newbie and I created an eyebrow using the 2d animation blender something but I am stuck because I don't know how to apply this to my character. (This is the youtube video I watched for creating the eyebrow) >>>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJwMb1kb0W8

In the video there was no explanation what exact file format was used to export the eyebrows and he only says use empty(?) to bring up the eyebrow. I googled here and there but I could not find any clear directions how to exactly use empty in that specific way. Since I don't know how what file format I'm supposed to use for the eyebrow I just exported it as a FBX but when I import  it to my character...It looks totally white. No texture..no color nothing :(

I am so confused and honestly frustrated because I am almost done creating my character :(
I really want to finish this as soon as possible ....I would really appreciate some help if anyone knows how to bring up the eyebrow just like in the youtube video :)

[image: problem with applying eyebrow to character]

Comment: When you have made a character and eyebrows in Blender but in two files you don't need to import/export them as FBX. You can use File > Append to add data objects from another blend file. An *Empty* is an object like cube, it's just not rendered, often used to control other objects.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for answering my question !! That really helped :) lol  I tried it out but I noticed I had another problem  when I was trying to apply the eyebrow by using the Shrink warp modifier to the face I noticed that the eyebrow's mesh deform modifier was not working properly and the eyebrows cage and the eyebrow lines aren't binding even when the eyebrow lines are contained in the cage :( so it keeps on separating ...

Comment: I tried unbinding it, checked that all the meshes involved have had their rotation+scaling cleared/applied...bind it again and it still does not work  if possible could you please check what maybe causing the problem? I would really appreciate any and all timely assistance if possible...Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have you checked for flipped normals? If you want you can upload your blend file here https://pasteall.org/blend/ You can upload the eyebrows only. After the upload, you will get a new URL address. Copy it and paste it here to grant access to the file.

Comment: Here is the eyebrow file :) >> https://pasteall.org/blend/6dbc79734ec744c7bf853b9237974fe6

Comment: Thank you so  much for always helping out!! You really are the best 

Comment: Hi. Your eyebrow works fine. Just make sure you bind the *Surface Deform* modifier of the cage (*Plane.001*) before you deform or activate the *Shrinkwrap* modifier of the controller (*Plane*, you should give them proper names ;-) To parent the empty you need to switch to another workspace like *Layout*. You won't see it in the *2D Animation* workspace (confused me). Also make sure the origins are at the right positions, and apply *Scale* and *Rotation*.

Comment: Oh Thank you for checking it ! I guess there's a problem with my character then :( I'll try one more time ..Thank you so much for helping out :)